# How many months Bank Statement and how much should we have for UK via

Tags: visas

1. May I know how many months of bank statement i need for UK visit visa ?
2. How much do i need to keep in the bank ( SDG 3000 to 5000) ?
3. I saw the requirement of visa which included the building society book . Must i provide or just the bank statement ?

I'm Myanmar citizen and working in SG . I'm planning to go UK 2020 Aug with my friend . I'm planning to prepare for the bank statement .